# ASP.NET login.aspx works locally (LAN) but loops when accessing remotely

Tags: asp.net, iis, remote-access, lan

I'm trying to access my website remotely (via Public IP), the website loads and all but I can't do anything since it keeps reloading the login.aspx and won't go to default.aspx but if I do it locally (LAN) it works normally.

I've triple checked the configs and I literally have no idea what could be behind this since (AFAIK) it technically should work the same way locally (LAN) and remotely (via Public IP).

Comment: Have you tried deleting your cookies? Sometimes I get the same, fixes by removing cookies

Comment: I did and I tried in 3 different phones and 2 computers, but I guess I'll try it again, "third time's a charm" even though I'm way past that stage. :(
Edit: Didn't work... AGAIN.

Comment: Could you post the Looped URL? It sounds just like your external user don't have access to your login page which cause a form authentication loop to itself. So have you enabled anonymous authentication for login.aspx from external? Did you set any authorization rule or IP restriction?

Comment: I could post the URL, but due to the nature of the website itself and it's purpose, I can't let anyone create an account or give anyone access since it contains medical data, so I guess it wouldn't make sense if I did that.
I have anonymous authentications enabled and I don't have any IP restrictions or auth rules that could potentially make it loop.

Comment: You don't need to post the exact URL. We just need to know how to the infinite loop looks like.  Besides, hve you tried failed request tracing?